# Show "Read more" link only when inserted manually

Tags: customization

So far I have only been able to find removing "read more" completely from the main page or setting a post length.  On our blog, sometimes our posts are short (and we don't want to use the "excerpt" function) and therefore do not need the "read more", while other times they are long and the authors want to insert "read more" at their personal preferred spot.
Is there some way to include "read more" just when it is inserted manually?  We are using the Hueman theme.
Thank you!

Comment: Normally, this is not a theme setting. Can you code?

Comment: Can I code?  I am very new to coding.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a blog with different articles on your start page you have to change the "content.php" in your theme folder.
On line 27 (if the file is not changed) you should change the function "the_excerpt()" to "the_content()" which then fetches the complete post until a manually set "read more" in the respective post.
That should do the trick, but maybe you have to tweak the css too (and/or your posts), to make it look good.

Comment: I changed the "the_excerpt()" to "the_content()" in the functions.php file to fetch the complete post.  I don't see this in the theme "content.php" file?

Comment: Then your theme was already changed by someone else? Does ist work for you as intended?
You should comment what you changed and why and also maybe save the original line as a comment, so that you can easily go back if something strange occurs.